# .gitignore, adminLTE and changes in vendor, suggestion?

Tags: php, laravel, git, gitignore, adminlte

I'm trying to configure adminLTE in Laravel project. I have found a way of modifying it, but when I want to modify it, it has to be done in vendor/jeroennoten/laravel.../views/master.blade.php or page.blade.php for basics and if I want to modify menus and navs it has to be done in vendor/jeroennoten/laravel-adminlte/config/adminlte.php

By default in .gitignore is also vendor folder. Now, I'm wondering, how to manage all this with GIT cause I'm changing things in vendor file? What is the recommendation and/or best practice? Try not to change anything in vendor, and make views in resource folder (what looks kind of huge work for adminLTE), or to use i.e. !vendor/jeroennoten in .gitignore, track all changes and update it on gitHub.
Is there any additional things I should do if someone wants to pull the project so he/she can see changes in vendor.

I'm new to this, so if this seems kind of dummy question or there is completely different approach please have understanding.

Comment: Have you read https://github.com/jeroennoten/Laravel-AdminLTE#7-customize-views ? Not having used this lib I can't say it will work, but worth a try.

Comment: Just cant believe I haven't seen this. I had some problems with integration with Laravel 5.8 and focused on that, totally forgot to see documentation to the end. Thanks @JonStirling, I'm jumping right on it.

Comment: BUT this question still can be explained, as I have changed default laravel auth. I have changed something in vendor/laravel/framework/src.../AuthenticateUser.php Should I just note that in instructions how to use when uploading project to gitHub, cause it's a small change? Or attach file with project?

Comment: You shouldn't change anything in the vendor folder. Next time you do a composer update or install, all of your changes will be wiped out.

Comment: What @Bryan said. If your answer to something is to makes changes in vendor which is volatile, you've probably asked the wrong question.

Comment: All clear now, thanks everybody.